# "?" in regular expression not working with Visual Studio 2008 find utility

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, find

I have two functions `getpeer` and `getpeerw`in my source code. I wanted to search both so, I use regular expression `getpeerw?` with VS find utility in Visual Studio 2008, but it does not find any of the mentioned function.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the Find option for Regular Expressions? You should see a section of the Find dialog to expand to set Find options.

Comment: @Wayne Yes.. I have used Regular Expression option. To clarify, other option is Wildcards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio 2008 regex syntax is a bit weird and uses a number of very non-standard constructs if you're used to a more modern Perl-Compatible type of Regular Expressions. If I remember correctly there is no *zero or one* matching option, only *zero or more* and *one or more*.

All [options are clearly documented on MSDN and you can swap back and forth between VS2008 and VS2013 to check the differences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.90).aspx). The later versions use a much more modern regex syntax.

To get what you want you probably want to use `(w|())`. which basically gives you `w` or *`nothing`*.

And indeed as others are suggesting, make sure you have enabled Regular Expression Matching in the Find window:

[image]

Comment: `getpeer(w|)` results in error message, but `getpeer(w|())` and `getpeer(w)|()` behave as desired.

Comment: Updated :) Thanks, next time you can also propose an edit instead of a comment ;)